# How do I show an aggregated "amount" with $ symbol on Kibana dashboard?

Tags: currency, dashboard, kibana

Kibana index show the amount field as "number", How do I show it as a $ value after "sum" on visualization? how do I tell it is a "currency" field?

Answer (score 0):

Wait for Kibana 4.1 to address this issue:  https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1543